# Displaying Parse Data to ContainerList

Tags: codenameone

I want to display data from Parse in a list from GamesScores class using Container in Codename One, this is what I've tried so far and it's not showing anything nor giving any errors:

```
Container container = findListCont();
        container.setLayout(BoxLayout.y());
        container.setScrollableY(true);


        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
        List<ParseObject> results = (List<ParseObject>) query.find();
        System.out.println("Size: " + results.size());

        container.addComponent(results, f);
```

Please help me out, I'm a new in Codename One. If there tutorials on it, please share or anything to help me achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually shocked this isn't failing. You are using the add constraint to place the object result as a constraint and you add the form object into the container...

You need to loop over the results and convert them to components to add into the layout. It also seems that you are using the old GUI builder which I would recommend against.

Generally something like this rough pseudo code should work assuming you are using a box Y layout:

```
for(ParseObject o : results) {
   MultiButton mb = new MultiButton(o.getDisplayValue());
   f.add(mb);
}
f.revalidate();
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried it and it gives me this error: "for-each not applicable to expression type
  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    List<ParseObject>"

Comment: Make sure your import statement refers to `java.util.List` and not `com.codename1.ui.List`

Comment: Thanks it works, the only thing that doesn't work is the onClicklistener.

Comment: What `onClicklistener`?

Comment: I wanna go to another form when I click an item in the list.

Comment: Use `addActionListener` on the multi button and write the code you want there.